# SQL query for Most frequent value in the row

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Database looks something similar to the below one.

```
ID   A1   A2   A3    A4
7   2.31 2.31 2.31  2.32
8   2.32 2.32 2.32  2.32
9   2.31 2.3  2.31  2.31
10  2.32 2.3  2.32  2.31
```

Now I'm looking for an SQL query which gives the output as below (picks the most frequent value from A1,A2,A3,A4 for each value in the ID and display it in the column A)

```
ID  A
7   2.31
8   2.32
9   2.31
10  2.32
```

Can someone please help me on this..

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  Your current table design is a poor choice for this type of query.

Comment: Since you are a beginner!!!you should read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**this**](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) before asking a question on SO. It will help the SO community.

Comment: Version of the server is SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT ID, x.A
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 t.A
   FROM (VALUES (A1), (A2), (A3), (A4)) AS t(A)
   GROUP BY t.A
   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS x
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cf5a5/1)

Comment: Awesome. My first thought was to use unpivot then aggregate then row_number to get top in groups. But the VALUES approach is much more succinct.

Comment: @Rohit Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by using PIVOT, like below:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE1 (
    ID INT, 
    A1 DECIMAL(10,2), 
    A2 DECIMAL(10,2),
    A3 DECIMAL(10,2), 
    A4 DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO #TABLE1 VALUES (7,2.31,2.31,2.31,2.32);
INSERT INTO #TABLE1 VALUES (8,2.32,2.32,2.32,2.32);
INSERT INTO #TABLE1 VALUES (9,2.31,2.3,2.31,2.31);
INSERT INTO #TABLE1 VALUES (10,2.32,2.3,2.32,2.31);
GO

select * from #TABLE1


SELECT ID, A
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID, A, count(A) as 'RepeatCount',
        rank() over (partition by ID order by ID, count(A) desc) as 'ranked'
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, A1, A2, A3, A4
        FROM #TABLE1
    ) pvt
    UNPIVOT (
        A FOR COL IN (A1, A2, A3, A4)
    )AS unpvt
    group by ID, A
)A
WHERE ranked = 1
ORDER BY ID

drop table #TABLE1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since there's only 4 values involved with each row, there's only a need to check for a single matching pair. Because if there's a tie, you can return either of the two correctly.

Exploiting this, you can pull it off using nothing but if/else logic like so:

```
SELECT ID,
IIF (
  A1 = A2 OR A1 = A3 OR A1 = A4,
  A1,
  IIF (
    A2 = A3 OR A2 = A4,
    A2,
    A3)
) A FROM mytable
```

[Proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cf5a5/6/0)

The solution posted by Giorgos Betsos has cleaner, safer looking logic.
But pretty sure my approach is less resource heavy.